# Subclipse JavaHL zip source for manual installation

Tags: windows, eclipse, subclipse, javahl

We are working to install updated versions of Eclipse and Subclipse on a few VMs in a data center.  The firewall in place for this dc prevents us from downloading anything from the Eclipse download sites or marketplace.  Instead, we download to computers outside of the data center, move the files, and install things manually.

The OS for these VMs is Windows Server, a mix of 2012, 2016, and 2019.  The Eclipse IDE for Java 2021-12 can be installed without issue.  It appears that we can also install the SVNKit (org.tmatesoft.svn_1.10.3.zip) and Subclipse 4.3.3 (subclipse-4.3.3.zip) successfully, provided that the SVNKit is installed first.

Subclipse does not provide an option to install JavaHL.  We are struggling to locate a proper zip file that can be used to manually install the JavaHL part.  The files from github return error messages in Eclipse that it cannot find a jar to install.  Suggestions and advice on how this could be installed without access to the marketplace or update sites would be greatly appreciated.

[Eclipse message for JavaHL zip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPgjt.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Mark provided us a link within the github space he maintains to exactly what we were looking for.  The javahl windows code needed was found here, nicely prepared in zip files by version - https://github.com/subclipse/updates/tree/main/javahl

We used 1.14.0, found here - https://github.com/subclipse/updates/blob/main/javahl/subclipse-javahl-1.14.0.zip

Thank you Mark!